# Two nav bars, both hide on scroll

Tags: html, css

Using the CSS, HTML method to get the fantastic function of hiding navbar on scroll up to work.  I changed the variables in the second script in case it confuses the compiler.

I can get the first `navbar(id="navbar")` to hide no problem, thank you stack overflow, and with some finesse, I can get the second `navbar(id="secondLineNav")` to disappear but won't come back

**CSS**

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; /*take this out for vertical list*/
  /*transition: 0.8S all;*/
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: space-between;

  /*border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers 
  width: calc(100% / 6);*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

navul li: hover {
  /*background-color: #f39c1a4b;*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lexend Mega", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: #dddcdc;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav .active {
  background-color: rgb(191 191 191 / 13%);
}

#secondLineNav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 9%);
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 81px;
}

#secondLineNav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#secondLineNav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*border-right: 1px solid #dddcdc;*/
}

#secondLineNav ul li::after {
  content: "|";
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
}

#secondLineNav ul li:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

#secondLineNav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lexend Mega", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: #dddcdc;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffest || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      navbar.style.top = "-90px";
    } else {
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var lastScrollTopb = 81;
  secondLineNav = document.getElementById("secondLineNav");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var scrollTopb = window.pageYOffest || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTopb > lastScrollTopb) {
      secondLineNav.style.top = "-90px";
    } else {
      secondLineNav.style.top = "81";
    }
    lastScrollTopb = scrollTopb;
  });
</script>


    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><b><a href="indexWEATHER.html">Weather</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexRace.html">Race</a></b>
            <li><b><a href="index.html"><img src="img/Burgee_WSC.png" 
    width="30" height="10"></a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexTour.html">Tour</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexMembers.html#top">club</a></b></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <nav id="secondLineNav">
        <ul>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">How To</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">NOR</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Results</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Pro SignUp</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Training</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Trophy Room</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Charity Regatta</a></b></li>
            
        </ul>


      </nav>
```

Comment: Please also share your HTML code

Comment: thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing `px` after the 81 in the following line.

```
secondLineNav.style.top = "81";
```

It works in the first example because in css 0 does not need to be suffixed with the unit, but other numbers do.

To make your example work i just added a height to the body so i could scroll, moved the script tags to the end so html would be loaded when the script run and added the `px` missing.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; /*take this out for vertical list*/
  /*transition: 0.8S all;*/
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: space-between;

  /*border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers 
  width: calc(100% / 6);*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

navul li: hover {
  /*background-color: #f39c1a4b;*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lexend Mega", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: #dddcdc;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav .active {
  background-color: rgb(191 191 191 / 13%);
}

#secondLineNav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 9%);
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 81px;
}

#secondLineNav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#secondLineNav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*border-right: 1px solid #dddcdc;*/
}

#secondLineNav ul li::after {
  content: "|";
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
}

#secondLineNav ul li:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

#secondLineNav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lexend Mega", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: #dddcdc;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:800px">
  <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><b><a href="indexWEATHER.html">Weather</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexRace.html">Race</a></b>
            <li><b><a href="index.html"><img src="img/Burgee_WSC.png" 
    width="30" height="10"></a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexTour.html">Tour</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="indexMembers.html#top">club</a></b></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <nav id="secondLineNav">
        <ul>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">How To</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">NOR</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Results</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Pro SignUp</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Training</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Trophy Room</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="*.html">Charity Regatta</a></b></li>
            
        </ul>


      </nav>
</body>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffest || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      navbar.style.top = "-90px";
    } else {
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var lastScrollTopb = 81;
  secondLineNav = document.getElementById("secondLineNav");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var scrollTopb = window.pageYOffest || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTopb > lastScrollTopb) {
      secondLineNav.style.top = "-90px";
    } else {
      secondLineNav.style.top = "81px";
    }
    lastScrollTopb = scrollTopb;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: fantastic! Thank you for your time.